# jQuery form validation messages not displaying

Tags: jquery, validation

I wrote this code to validate input with JavaScript since my session error message from backend does not show in browser when there is an error. This code does not display as I expected it to do and I have coded it.

What is wrong with this code?

How do I make this code work?

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
I wrote this code to validate input with JavaScript since my session error message from backend does not show in browser when there is an error. This code does not display as I expected it to do and I have coded it.

What is wrong with this code?

How do I make this code work?
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

````js
```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var number = /([0-9])/;
      var alphabets = /([a-zA-Z])/;
      var special_characters = /([~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,-,_,+,=,?,>,<])/;
      var password = $('#password').val();
      var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
      var surname = $('#surname').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var passwordConf = $('#passwordConf').val();
      var phonenumber = $('#phonenumber').val();

  

      //surname on focus

      $("#surname").focus(function() {
        $("#insu").toggle();
        $("#surname").focus();
        return false;
      });

      // Validating surname Field else 
$("#surname").change(function(){
      if (surname.match(alphabets)) {
        $("#vasu").toggle();
        $("#surname").focus();
        return false;
      }
});


      $("#password").focus(function() {
        $("#pswd_info").toggle();
        $("#password").focus();
      });

$("#password").change(function(){
      if (password.match(/[A-z]/)) {
        $("#inalpha").hide();
        $("#vaalpha").show();
      }

      if (password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        $("#inca").hide();
        $("#vaca").show();
      }

      if (password.match(special_characters)) {
        $("#insc").hide();
        $("#vasc").show();
      }

      if (password.match(number)) {
        $("#innu").hide();
        $("#vanu").show();
      }

      if (password.length >= 8) {
        $("#inpl").hide();
        $("#vapl").show();
        return false;
      }});
 if (!passwordConf.match(password)) {
        $("#inpC").show();
        $("#passwordConf").focus();
        return false;
      } else if (phonenumber.length < 11) {
        $("#inpn").show();
        return false;
      } else
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
          alert("Form Submitted Successfuly! An email has been sent to your  email addresss for verification " + $('#email').val() + "");
          return true;
        });
````

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="register.php" method="post"><br>
  <p id="head"></p>
  <label for="surname">Surname</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="<?= htmlentities($surname) ?>" required>

  <span class="valid" id="vasu" style="display: none;"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">Good</i></span>
  <span class="invalid" id="insu" style="display: none;"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">Surname must be of alphabet format </i></span><br>

  <label for="password">Choose a Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?= htmlentities($password) ?>" required>

  <div id="pswd_info">
    <span style=" display: inline-block;" id="inalpha" class="invalid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">At least <strong>one letter</strong></i><span>
                        <span style=" display: none;" id="inalpha" class="valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">At least <strong>one letter</strong></i><span><br>

                        <span style="display:inline-block;" id="inca" class="invalid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></i></span>
    <span style="display:none;" id="vaca" class="valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></i></span><br>


    <span style="display:inline-block;" id="innu" class="invalid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">At least <strong>one number</strong></i></span>
    <span style="display: none;" id="vanu" class="valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">At least <strong>one number</strong></i></span><br>

    <span style="display:inline-block;" id="insc" class="invalid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">At least <strong>one Special character </strong></i></span>
    <span style="display: none;" id="vasc" class="valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">At least <strong>one Special character</strong></i></span><br>

    <span style=" display: inline-block; " id="inpl" class="invalid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></i></span>
    <span style=" display: none;" id="vapl" class="valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></i></span><br>
  </div>

  <label for="passwordConf">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="passwordConf" name="passwordConf" required>

  <span class="invalid" id="inpC" style="display: none;"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">Both password must match </i></span><br>
  <br>
```

Comment: Your `$(document).ready(` function is missing the closing brackets. And you have `<span>` at the end of the `At least <strong>one letter</strong>` span instead of `</span>`

Comment: The validation code all needs to be inside an event handler. You're running it when the page first loads.

Comment: @Barmar I get this error and i dont know what to do.  jquery.min.js:2 
        
       Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: That means you have infinite recursion in your code.

Comment: @Barmar how do i identify that and what do i do? i edited my code.

Comment: Use the stack trace in the debugger. You'll see a function that's being called repeatedly.